# Vim en IDE Dev C/C++

Tags: dev-c++, plugin, ide, vim

Buen día con todos, tengo una duda en cuestión a si puedo integrar vim a el IDE DEV C++ puesto a que es el IDE que mas uso por su eficiencia y manejo de archivos ( también que demora menos en copilar que el Visual Studio *es solo mi opinión no hate), últimamente me decidí por aprender a usar vim para maximizar mi eficiencia al programar,  pero el programar desde consola y hacer todo los procesos que requiere copilar y ejecutar se me hace mas complejo, y trate de ver si podía usar vim en el IDE mencionado anteriormente, puesto que lo uso en el VS code cuando programo en JS y PHP, pero no e visto que se puedad agregar plugins a ese IDE.

En resumen: hay alguna forma de integrar vim en DEV C++? o debo mudar de IDE a uno que permita copilar y ejecutar en la misma interfaz y tanta facilidad y tambien permita usar vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por desgracia, hasta donde tengo entendido, no es posible hacerlo directamente. Dev-C++ no dispone de una consola integrada, por lo que no podrás usar vim dentro de la misma interfaz.

Una posible opción es utilizar vim desde la línea de comandos e instalar el mismo compilador que usa Dev-C++, llamado MingW32, lo puedes obtener aquí: http://www.mingw.org/
Sin embargo, con esto no estarías usando su interfaz de manejo de archivos.

Si realmente quieres trabajar con vim, probablemente te sea mejor buscar otro IDE, o ir editando los ficheros en vim y compilando aparte en Dev, aunque es algo que no recomiendo.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda , si cuento con el MingGW porque con ello copilo y ejecuto desde consola de Git o CMD pero , como mencioné en la publicación , se me es muy complicado , que otro IDE me recomendarías? estaba pensando en usar el VS Code y lo copilaba en DEV C++

Comment: No suelo programar en C++, pero cuando lo hago uso VS Code o CLion, que está bastante bien. Otra opción que gusta a mucha gente (aunque a mi personalmente no me convence demasiado) es Netbeans.